# Is there a way to monitor network traffic/egress from Google Cloud Run console?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have been going through the Google Cloud Run and StackDriver documentation, but I am not able to find a way to monitor network traffic generated by a Managed Cloud Run Service. Google itself is also not very helpful here since Google Cloud Run egress network are such generic terms...

The metrics Requests, Latency, CPU and RAM  are right there in the console. So is all the logging in StackDriver,  but all my costs come from egress to the internet. Only in the Billing section can I find a total per day for egress costs, but that is not really helpful. Is there a way to monitor egress for a Cloud Run Service from within the Cloud Console, or do I need to build my own egress monitoring?

Edit: What I mean is just like the Request/s CPU/s and RAM.s graphs I would also like to see a bytes in/out graph to monitor the running container.

Comment: I never see this feature. You can ask for this in the public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Are you trying to monitor how many **bytes** are sent/received by your Cloud Run applications? It's not entirely clear what "monitoring network" means as you might appreciate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited the original question, i hope it is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to graph the monitoring of in/out bytes on stackdriver. However as mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere  you can create a feature request for this function.

You can check for stackdriver current feature request or create your own, [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Cloud Run now has added metrics which measure incoming and outgoing network traffic. 
 You can see more details in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#run/container/network/received_bytes_count)